# What is background color of uipicker control?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using a uipicker as an input view for a text control.  I also have a toolbar set up as an accessory input view.  I would like the toolbar tint to match the picker.  I have tried using the magnifier tool on the color chooser to get the RGB for the picker, but when I use these RGB values to set the tint on the toolbar I get get a close, but not exact match.

Is there anyway to figure out exactly the background color of the picker?  None of the palettes in the color chooser seem to have this particular shade of gray with a slight hint of blue.

Thanks,

Jenny

Comment: For all you know it may be pure 255 white, unless you're referring to the background color of the area surrounding the reels.

Comment: Yes, not necessarily the "Background Color," but what the user might perceive as the color of the control.  I want my input view and accessory input view look like they might be one single control.

Answer (score 1):

The border consists of a gradient for the top half and a solid color for the bottom half:

[image: UIPicker with color values]

As for the 'white' background, the brightest part is a #fafafa to #5f627c gradient.

Comment: When I bring up the up the picker view on my iPod Touch, it is much lighter in color (and with a hint of blue mixed into the gray) than the one pictured in your post and even #666666 is too dark.